# Do graduate studies and/or postdoc experience count as work experience for a P.ENG. application in Canada?

Tags: canada, certification

Given the following credentials:

- a 2-year Master's of Applied Science degree (engineering) from a Canadian institute
- a Ph.D. (engineering) from a European university (acquired within 2 years and 3 months)
- 2 years of postdoctoral experience in a Canadian university

I intend to apply for the P.Eng. certification. So, can one assert which partition of the years above will count as required experience years for this certificate?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably depends on exactly what you were doing and for how many hours total...

Comment: You need to ask then or read the documentation.

Comment: @SolarMike: I have already checked the files which are pretty obscure in this regard. But thanks for your spam comment!

Comment: @Pinton Have you contacted the body that awards the certificate? That should give you a useful answer. They know their criteria better than we do.

Comment: Can't answer for Canada, but in Texas: (a) The only one that *might* count as experience would be the postdoc, and that would have to have been done under direct supervision of a licensed PEng who will sign off on the experience record.  Likely part of the time would count and part won't.  (b) While education beyond your ABET BS in engineering does not count as experience, it does reduce the experience requirement, by something like 1 year per degree, i.e. one for master's and another for PhD.

Comment: Engineering in Canada is regulated by province. Which province are you applying for?

Comment: @DJClayworth: Ontario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Engineering in Canada is regulated at the provincial level, so you need to know which province's regulatory body you are applying to. I'm going to assume it's Ontario, because that's the most likely province and it has a nominal 48 month experience requirement.

Professional Engineers of Ontario has an ["are you ready to apply" page](https://www.peo.on.ca/apply/become-professional-engineer/application-requirements#:%7E:text=The%20academic%20requirement%20to%20apply,of%20a%20technical%20examination%20program.). When you get to the question about work experience it asks if you have 48 months of **professional** experience, and if you say "no" then it tells you that you are not ready to apply. Academic experience is not usually considered "professional", although I also assume there is a way for very experienced academics to become members. In any case, actual assessment is done on a "competency" basis where you write a summary of your experience and they assess your suitability. I would expect that 24 months of academic experience will not give you the professional competency they expect.

Comment: It’s not stated in the question, but there’s a very important wrinkle to this problem: Being an engineering professor in Canada requires that you register as a professional engineer, e.g. https://uwaterloo.ca/engineering/faculty-and-staff/professional-registration. When I was on the job market a decade ago and considering north-of-the-border openings, I remember finding that there was a procedure for getting PE accreditation for junior academics; I don’t remember the details.